# Redefinition of class in CPP File Error

Tags: c++, class

I know there are plenty of questions like these, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

Okay, I am trying to make simple fraction calculator than can add or subtract any number of functions and write the answer as a reduced fraction.

*Example: input=
3/2 + 4/
8
, output =
2*

I am trying overload operators in order to accomplish this.

So in the program, I am trying to develop the input consists of an expression made of fractions separated by the operators '+'or '-'.

The number of fractions in the expression is arbitrary.

Each of the following 6 lines is an example of valid input expression:

```
1/2 + 3/4
1/2 -5/7+3/5
355/113
3    /9-21/    -7
4/7-5/-8
-2/-3+7/5
```

***The problem that I am having is that in when I run my Main CPP program it has a class redefinition error:***

```
fraction.cpp:6:7: error: redefinition of 'Fraction'
class Fraction
      ^
./Fraction.h:7:7: note: previous definition is here
class Fraction{
```

However, that should not be a problem because I declared the class and member functions in my header files and defined them in my CPP file.

My following code is below:

**Header File**

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Fraction{

    public: 
    Fraction(int , int );
    int fraction(int,int);
    void reduce_fraction(int *,  int *);
    Fraction& operator+(const Fraction& n);
    Fraction& operator-(const Fraction& n);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const  Fraction& n);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, const Fraction& n);


};
#endif
```

**CPP File**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <stdexcept>

class Fraction
{
public: 
    Fraction::Fraction(int a, int b);
    int find_gcd(int n1, int n2); 

    void reduce_fraction(int *nump,  int *denomp) 
    {
      int gcd;   
      gcd = find_gcd(*nump, *denomp);
      *nump = *nump / gcd;
      *denomp = *denomp / gcd;

      if ((*denomp<0 && *nump < 0 ))
    {
        *denomp*=-1;
        *nump*=-1;
    }
    else if (*denomp < 0 &&  *nump >0){
        *denomp*=-1;

    }
if ( *denomp ==0) {
        throw invalid_argument( "Error: zero denominator" );
    }
    }



Fraction& Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& n) {
    int denom = *denomp * n.denom;
    int numera = (*nump * n.numera) + (n.denom * n.nump);
    return Fraction(numera,denom);

}

Fraction& Fraction::operator-(const Fraction& n) {
    int denom = *denomp * n.denom;
    int numera = (*nump * n.numera) - (n.denom* n.nump);
    return Fraction(numera, denom);
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Fraction& n)
{
    if (n.numera == 0)
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return os;
    }
    else if (n.numera == n.denom)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
        return os
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n.numera << '/' << n.denom << endl;
        return os;
    }
}

friend istream& operator>>(istream &os, Fraction& n)
{
    char slash = 0;
    return is >> n.numera >> slash >> n.denom;

    }
};


















#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <stdexcept>

class Fraction
{
public: 
    Fraction::Fraction(int a, int b);
    int find_gcd(int n1, int n2); 

    void reduce_fraction(int *nump,  int *denomp) 
    {
      int gcd;   
      gcd = find_gcd(*nump, *denomp);
      *nump = *nump / gcd;
      *denomp = *denomp / gcd;

      if ((*denomp<0 && *nump < 0 ))
    {
        *denomp*=-1;
        *nump*=-1;
    }
    else if (*denomp < 0 &&  *nump >0){
        *denomp*=-1;

    }
if ( *denomp ==0) {
        throw invalid_argument( "Error: zero denominator" );
    }
    }



Fraction& Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& n) {
    int denom = *denomp * n.denom;
    int numera = (*nump * n.numera) + (n.denom * n.nump);
    return Fraction(numera,denom);

}

Fraction& Fraction::operator-(const Fraction& n) {
    int denom = *denomp * n.denom;
    int numera = (*nump * n.numera) - (n.denom* n.nump);
    return Fraction(numera, denom);
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Fraction& n)
{
    if (n.numera == 0)
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return os;
    }
    else if (n.numera == n.denom)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
        return os
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n.numera << '/' << n.denom << endl;
        return os;
    }
}

friend istream& operator>>(istream &os, Fraction& n)
{
    char slash = 0;
    return is >> n.numera >> slash >> n.denom;

    }
};
```

**MAIN CPP FILE**

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Fraction x(2,3);
  Fraction y(6,-2);

  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;

  cin >> y;
  cout << y << endl;
  Fraction z = x + y;
  cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << z << endl;
}
```

*I am essentially having trouble with understanding why I am getting the previous definition error and how exactly to fix it. Also, if you see anything else wrong with my implementation in this program I would appreciate you telling me!*

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to define member functions in `Fraction.cpp` is not like this:

```
class Fraction
{
public: 
  void reduce_fraction(int *nump,  int *denomp) 
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

but rather like this:

```
void Fraction::reduce_fraction(int *nump,  int *denomp) 
{
  ...
}
```

More generally, you should not write this much code before testing any of it.

Comment: so I would omit the class Fraction {}

Comment: @XiJiaopin: Yes, and add "Fraction::". **Try it with the simplest code you can invent.**

Comment: Okay did I implement it wrongly if I got : error: out-of-line declaration of a member must be a definition

Comment: @XiJiaopin: Please show what changes you made to get this new error.